# Index raster brick

Tags: r, indexing, raster

I'm working with a raster brick with 365 layers in R using the `raster` package. I want to transform all values in the raster brick for pixel index `r,c` from layer index `start:stop`.  I've figured out how to extract these values from the brick:

```
year_mask[[start:stop]][r,c]
```

...but when I try to assign a value to this subset of the raster brick, say by doing the following:

```
year_mask[[start:stop]][r,c] <- NA
```

..then I get the following error:

`Error in v[] <- value : 
  incompatible types (from S4 to logical) in subassignment type fix`

Any thoughts on how to assign a value or NA to a space-time index of a raster brick?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
year_mask[cellFromRowCol(year_mask,r,c)][start:stop] <- NA
```

Here, I'm assuming that `r` and `c` are scalars, and I'm using `cellFromRowCol` to get the cell index from the row and column indices.

If you have `r` and `c` as vectors of row and column indices and you want each row/col pair from those, see `?cellFromRowCol`, then do the following:

```
cinds <- cellFromRowCol(year_mask,r,c)
year_mask[cinds][1:length(cinds), start:stop] <- NA
```

In both cases `year_mask[cinds]` returns a `matrix` with rows for each cell indexed and all layers as columns. The subsequent index indexes into this matrix.

If instead you want cells from all the combinations of `r` and `c`, then use `cellFromRowColCombine` to get the `cinds`.

Hope this helps.